# Are the specs for the "Ears of the World" challenge reasonable?

Tags: power, batteries, kits, radio, design

I saw a post today on the Make blog about a challenge to create an extremely cheap FM/SW radio kit for developing nations. The organization sponsoring the challenge distributes donated wind-up powered Grundig radios, but they're relatively expensive, get stolen, can't be repaired, etc.

The specs they are looking for are certainly challenging, but may all be reasonable except for the power. They are asking that the radio be powered by a single AA battery (it may also have a solar cell) and contain a LED bright enough to use as a small lamp.

You can read the specs here: [FM Radio Challenge](http://blog.makezine.com/archive/2010/09/maker_challenge_fm_radio_kit_for_th.html)

My question is whether this community thinks that these specs are just written by non-experts. Is a practical device do-able with that power? Assume the price requirement could be met (the solar cell may be the priciest part). If a single AA was chosen due to its ubiquity, would a high quality rechargeable battery still meet the needs?

And yes, I did really want to put this challenge in front of the readers here by putting it in the form of a real question. Note that it is tagged community wiki.

Comment: *Note that it is tagged community wiki.*  Noted.  Now I'm wondering why this is community wiki.  Can you explain?

Answer (score 2):

Sure it's practical, the specs sound reasonable - there's [tiny FM receivers](http://gizmodo.com/5456687/motz-mini-fm-radio-is-a-serious-choking-hazard) available on the market that run off small 3v button batteries.

I think the hardest part will be designing a radio that is cost effective and can be built without a soldering iron.

It sounds like a great challenge tho, will be really interesting to see what ideas people come up with :)

@ Cmpalmer - Do you intend to enter the competition yourself?

Comment: Not likely. I was just curious and I'm looking forward to seeing what people come up with. The last radio I built was a crystal radio kit when I was a pre-teen, I think. There's no prize involved, just a put your heads together and see if you can create something to help out.